# JakeWharton ViewPagerIndicator update android support v4

Tags: java, android, plugins

I'm using [JakeWharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) library to ViewPager in my project.
I wanna add NotificationCompact to my project and we now this Notification is for blow API 16 but we need updated  android-support-v4 for add `NotificationCompact().Builder().build();`

but JakeWharton Just work with his android-support-v4 and its updated for 3 years ago ...

how add new android-support-v4 to my Project/lib direction and wanna call him in specify Class but i don't know how i can use it in specify Class...

Any idea or any library like that can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewPagerIndicator is still compatible with the latest versions of support-v4. I use the Circle and Underline indicators in some of my projects.

I copied the code I needed directly to my project but I believe you can also use a gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend but when i use copy lastest support-v4 to lib ViewPagerIndicator is stopped and i use Ecilipse version ...

Comment: What do you mean by "it stopped working"? Does it compile, do you see artifacts, do you have a crash with a stack trace? Please give more details.